# REST controller based on yii\rest\ActiveController does not accept any input data when trying to modify any record

Tags: php, json, rest, yii2

**tl;dr** *My Yii 2 app responds correctly to REST requests for fetching data (i.e. `GET`, but fails completely when I am trying to create some record (i.e. use `POST` HTTP verb or similar). What can be wrong?*

---

I have [created a blank Yii 2 project](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#installing-using-composer) based on *Yii 2 Advanced Project Template*:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application
php init
php yii migrate
```

I have [created a REST *UserController*](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#creating-controller) for already existing *User* model:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

I have [configured URL rules](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#configuring-url-rules):

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
    ],
]
```

I have also [enabled JSON input](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#enabling-json-input), if that matters:

```
'request' => [
    'parsers' => [
        'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    ]
]
```

And my application is working only for reading data, meaning that endpoints / requests like `GET /users` or `GET /users/12` are processed correctly.

But, when I try to create a new post for the first time using JSON:

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
    -XPOST "http://localhost/users" \
    -d '{"username": "example", "email": "user@example.com"}'
```

I can clearly see that my request's JSON (`{"username": "example", "email": "user@example.com"}`) gets totally ignored and user is created with empty `username` and `email` fields.

And when I try to invoke the above *curl* code for the second or following time, I am getting *Integrity constraint violation* exception with error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'\nThe SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `user` (`status`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (9, 1654291700, 1654291700)

Which also clearly proves that my input JSON is ignored.

This is by no means related to JSON input. I have tried to create a record using URL-encoded data to no avail:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: This is because REST ActiveControllers use REST actions, ie: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-viewaction
And they acquire the ID from query parameters. So you cannot send the ID in a json body, despite the JSON parser.
But you can send the POST and PUT params in the body as json.

Comment: Take a look at action parameters here:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#action-parameters

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice on RestController. But there still seems to be some problem with my application because (as you can see in paragraph second to the last) I am still not able to create a record using JSON (it is created with nullified fields) and you claim in your comment that this must be possible.

Comment: What are the "rules()" in your model? Is there a "fields()" function in your model, that isn't the inherited? Your JSON request seems fine, it should work, if your model is okay.

Comment: @BarneyK I have completely rewritten the question (and hopefully made it easier to read), because my following tests has proven that the very same problem exists also for Yii 2 Advanced App Template not just for a Yii 2 as a Micro-framework. Can you see it again? Thank you.

Comment: The `yii\rest\CreateAction` uses `Model::load()` method to load data from request body to  model's attributes. But, that method only loads data for attributes that are considered safe. You probably have no validation rules specified for your model so no attribute is considered safe and no data are loaded.

Comment: @MichalHynčica True, but as you can see, I am not defining any action of my own. I am only using `yii\rest\ActiveController`. My the only and entire REST controller has six lines in total and uses 100% solution provided by framework. Shouldn't this (all attribs) set as safe by default, by framework?

Comment: No, the attribute is considered "safe" when it's in list of attributes returned by `scenarios()` method for current scenario. Its default implementation generates the list of attributes from list of validation rules. So unless you've explicitly set validation rules or override `scenarios()` method your attributes are considered unsafe.

Comment: You're most probably right. I'll double check this and report. On the other hand, my question above is a direct copy of the [RESTful Web Services: Quick Start](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start) chapter in the Yii 2 Guide. In the second to end section ("[Trying It Out](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#trying-it-out)") they say that I can use `POST` etc. verbs, that they're implemented out of the box and they say nothing about making any attributes safe. In other words. Going step-by-step through above mentioned chapter brought me here.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Of course, you're right. Your comment answers and solves my problem. Will you turn it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in this case is not in parsing JSON body but rather in loading data into model.

The `yii\rest\CreateAction` uses [`Model::load()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#load()-detail) method to load data into attributes. But `load()` method only loads data into attributes that are considered "safe".

As "safe" are considered attributes that are returned in attributes list for current scenario by [`Model::scenarios()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#scenarios()-detail) method.
As stated in documentation for `scenarios()` method:

> The default implementation of this method will return all scenarios found in the rules() declaration.

So, if there are no validation rules in model, no attribute will be considered safe. Therefore, no attribute will be loaded.

There are two options how to make model load your data.
You can override `scenarios()` method to return list of your attributes for scenario default.

```php
public function scenarios(): array
{
    return [
        \yii\base\Model::SCENARIO_DEFAULT => ['your', 'attributes', ...],
        //or you can also use attributes() method here
        //\yii\base\Model::SCENARIO_DEFAULT => $this->attributes(),
    ];
}
```

Or, you can set proper validation rules in `rules()` method.
Because you are dealing with user inputs, setting proper validation rules is probably better idea.