# Enabling pretty URLs / urlManager completely breaks Yii 2 application runnikg as a REST micro-framework

Tags: php, rest, url, yii

**tl;dr** *My Yii 2 app, running [as a micro-framework](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-as-micro-framework), works just fine when using standard ("not pretty") URLs. However when the `urlManager` application component is enabled in the configuration, the entire application breaks completely and every call to it ends with 404.*

---

Following [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72486533/1469208), I am trying to run a minimalist version (micro framework) of Yii 2 app to act as an RESTful endpoint. I've followed [the guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-as-micro-framework) and everything seems to be working when I am calling a standard ("not pretty") URLs:

[image]

As suggested in [the guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-as-micro-framework), I have [enabled routing / pretty URLs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-routing) in my application:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'post'],
    ],
]
```

And suddenly my application stops working at all. It serves neither non-pretty:

[image]

nor pretty URLs:

[image]

It even fails to serve the default controller and action -- `site/index`.

What am I missing?

It seems that I have everything that I need. Following [the guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-as-micro-framework) I have:

- Created the micro-framework [application skeleton](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-as-micro-framework#installing-yii)
- Created [default controller](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-as-micro-framework#creating-the-first-controller) (`site`) and default action (`index`)
- Configured `db` component, run migrations and [created database](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-as-micro-framework#creating-a-rest-api)
- Created *PostController*
- Enabled routing by [adding Yii code](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-routing#routing) to application configuration (see code example above) and by creating corresponding *.httaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

What else must I do in order to make the whole thing work or what am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question comes from an misunderstanding. I wasn't aware that when pretty URLs are enabled then [`yii\rest\UrlRule::$pluralize`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$pluralize-detail) is set to *true* by default. Meaning that the request must be:

```
http://localhost/micro-app/posts
```

(plural controller name; notice "s" at the end)

Not:

```
http://localhost/micro-app/post
```

(singular controller name)

It is also completely normal that when pretty URLs are enabled then regular URLs doesn't work anymore. That's the reason for getting *404 File Not Found* on `http://localhost/micro-app/index.php?r=post` URL when pretty URLs are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
'enableStrictParsing' => true,
```

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer is not correct. Removing, commenting out or bringing this line back doesn't change anything. I can only upvote your answer for trying to help and because maybe it will work for someone else in some other scenario. I cannot accept it, because it does not solve the problem given in the question.